# I want to make a cut on the div like mentioned in the picture

Tags: html, css

I want to make cuts on the div like in the picture below. I have made the basic layout but I am not able to figure as to how to make those cuts.

[image: Demo]

Comment: You Can try using canvas or use a before selector to overlay the photo. You could overlay a triangle for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use

```
border-corner-shape:bevel;
border-radius: 0% 0% 50% 0%;
```

but it still doesnt work on browsers.this technic is for the future.
now what should we do for this moment.one approach is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/st2gppxz/1/

```
div {
    height: 250px;
    width: 200px;
    background: url(address of your image);
    position: relative;
}

div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 28%; right: 0;
    border-left: 70px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:180px solid white;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the basic idea.Now I can do it for my use.

Comment: Im glad I could be of assistance.have a nice day.